# One way binding objects in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I'm doing the official [Tour of heroes](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt3.html) tutorial on Angular 2. They pass an object into the target of another component:

```
<my-hero-detail [hero]="selectedHero"></my-hero-detail>
```

As far as I understand, `[hero]="selectedHero"` means one way binding the object *reference*. Thus, any modifications to `hero` within `my-hero-detail` will also affect `selectedHero`, since they reference the same object.

How can I enforce literal one way binding, like passing a deep? shallow? copy of `selectedHero` to `my-hero-detail`?

In Angular **1**.5, you can allegedly declare one way binding attributes in components: `scope: { hero: '<' }`. Is this missing in Angular 2?

--

I assume this was implemented by design, so we actually work by reference and copy only those properties that are needed.

Comment: By binding to a deep or shallow copy. Angular2 doesn't provide anything. Lookup cloning objects in TypeScript.

Comment: Yes, that's "by design" - but not of Angulars design, but of TypeScripts ;-)

Comment: Use an Object.assign({}, yourObject); to copy without keeping object two-way binded.

Comment: which would be a shallow copy, not a deep one. but a solution surely yes